# Problema al guardar los datos en una sesion

Tags: php

Tengo un problema al guardar los datos en una sesión, si añado un nuevo objecto me lo muestra pero si quiero añadir otro al recargar la página desaparace ese objecto añadido.

Supongo que la lógica esta bien hecha, cuando añado un nuevo alumno este se guarda en la session['alumno'] y cuando recargo la página con la función cargarDatosAlumno() debería cargar los datos guardados.

Tengo hecho lo siguiente :

```
<?php session_start();

        include_once("alumno.php");

        class Secretaria{

            public $alumnos = array();

            public function __construct(){

            }

            public function cargarDatosAlumno(){
                return isset($_SESSION['alumno']) ? $_SESSION['alumno'] : new Alumno();
            }

            //Guarda los datos del alumno en la sesion
            function guardarDatosAlumno($alumno){
                $_SESSION['alumno'] = $alumno;
            }
        }

        $secretaria = new Secretaria();

        // Cargamos los nuevos datos al recargar.
        $secretaria->cargarDatosAlumno();

        // Añadimos Alumnos.
        $alumno = new Alumno($_POST['nombre'],$_POST['apellido'],$_POST['dni']);
        array_push($secretaria->alumnos,$alumno);

        //Guardamos los datos en la session.
        $secretaria->guardarDatosAlumno($alumno);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Aquí:

```
public function cargarDatosAlumno(){
  return isset($_SESSION['alumno']) ? $_SESSION['alumno'] : new Alumno();
}
```

en realidad, no estás haciendo nada. Devuelves algo, que no usas en ninguna parte. Pero no cambias el valor inicial de `$secretaria->alumno`.

Debería ser

```
public function cargarDatosAlumno( ) {
  $this->alumnos = isset($_SESSION['alumno']) ? $_SESSION['alumno'] : new Alumno();
}
```

Comment: Tengo el _PHP_ algo *oxidado* ... espero haber usado la síntaxis correcta :-)

Comment: Tiene declarado `alumnos` como un array: `public $alumnos = array();` entonces supongo que lo correcto sería agregar el objeto al array de alumnos: **`$this->alumnos [] = isset($_SESSION['alumno']) ? $_SESSION['alumno'] : new Alumno();`** Aunque no entiendo bien cierta lógica aplicada en la clase, @InThaHouse, ¿? Si `Secretaria` manejará un array de alumnos, en ciertas partes no respetas esa intención.

Comment: @A.Cedano Creo que como guarda los `alumnos` (el array completo) en `$SESSION`, no es necesario. La idea de esa sentencia es que `$SESSION['alumno']` simpre contenga un alumno váido ... aunque, como un alumno válido es un *array* vacío, creo que se podía dejar con un simple `if( )` O_o

Comment: Tampoco me hagas mucho caso ... ha sido una respuesta rápida; seguro que se puede mejorar :-)

Comment: Yo la verdad nunca he trabajado con sesiones. Pero viendo que usa una clase `Secretaria` imagino que la idea es mantener un array de alumnos que son propiedad de esa clase. No sé si lo lógico sería entonces meter en la sesión un objeto `Secretaria` ¿? Realmente no alcanzo a entender cuál es la lógica que el OP intenta aplicar, de ahí mi duda.

Comment: Si, podrías meter una instancia de la clase ... si fueras a meter mas cosas, o hicieras previsión de futuro. O el código es realmente mínimo, o el OP está practicando con las sesiones :-)